# Asynchronous Drag and Drop to Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, winapi, .net-4.0, drag-and-drop, ole

Question:

I need a DragAndDrop solution to download a file on drop in a folder of Windows Explorer for C# & .NET 4.0. It should not be necessary to have the file on the computer. The file will be big enough that the drag-time won't be enough to get the download done. I have found various questions, even accepted answers, but nothing that works. The very closest thing to something working is this demo project:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/11/16/creating-something-from-nothing-and-knowing-it-developer-friendly-virtual-file-implementation-for-net-refined.aspx

How to implement this code to download a file as part of the action of putting it to the drop place in Windows Explorer?

Comment: Drag from where? From your application?

Comment: Yes, from my application. For example a textbox containing the URL of the file.

Comment: A possible option to consider is dropping a *shortcut* into the target directory (thus, dead quick to create the shortcut file), and the shortcut points to a file somewhere else (Downloads seems a good choice) which you subsequently fill as you download the file in the background. If you point the shortcut to the finished filename but tack .partial on the end while you're filling it up and rename when finished, then the shortcut would only access the file once it was fully downloaded. Not ideal, but might get you out of a spot.

Comment: @JTeagle this is not what I asked. I should also add that I'm aware that I can use a FileSystemWatcher to see where a artificially  created file was dropped, then download the file in the background and place it there, but I'm looking towards a more efficient solution.

Comment: Well, problem is that Explorer is stuck in 1995.  Lots of shell functionality is poorly mapped in .NET.  Google "drag and drop delayed rendering", first hit looks good.

Comment: Yes. The first Google hit doesn't work. I pointed to the link for the best working (but still not entirely working) solution, and believe me, I googled like hell. In fact, to answer this question I think one would have to have a good low-level windows knowledge, download the project I linked to and find out why it isn't working - for that run the demo app and try the drag&drop and see why the exception is thrown & how to fix this. Judging by the massive amount of questions and nonworking answers, this functionality is needed often before people decide they find it too complicated.

Comment: The article you found is the correct method. Now you get to debug why it's not working for you. Maybe your threading model is wrong. Explorer does generic content transfer. It doesn't know where the content is coming from - that's the application's responsibility.

Comment: The demo app doesn't work - if that doesn't work, I cannot expect to get this running for myself. Just a note: I assume this question is not answerable without downloading and trying out the demo app. Wise words about "hey this should work, it's your fault" don't help to solve the problem.

Comment: basically this is possible but complicated... you will need a shell extension and some other things to get it to work smoothly... MS says that this is not supported via .NET (even V 4!) although "possible"... posting a question basically saying "I found something that does not work - make it work" won't get you a working solution...google for "shell extension drag and drop" and come back with specific questions...

Comment: @Akku thanks for the edit... the link you posted won't get you a working solution... as I wrote in my previous comment: implementing such a mechanism is a big/serious undertaking (esp. with different Windows versions and/or .NET)... google for "shell extensions drag and drop" - this will help you see what is involved in such a solution and then you can come up with specific questions depending on where you are stuck in the implementation process...

Comment: The way to do this is to [put a stream on the clipboard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/03/19/8080215.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, as Yahia said in the comments it's not possible without a proper shell extension for the different versions of Windows and .NET. You might have luck with the link I posted, but for me it crashes the Explorer and the developer thinks it works fine.

My honest opinion is with only .NET you can only do it with a FileSystemWatcher via copying special .temp-files, watching where they land, doing your task and replacing the .temp files when your task is done. Sad Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Web browsers solve this problem every day. Simplifying their model a little, do this:

1. Make a little program that performs your download given appropriate command line parameters. This little program should pop up a window with a progress bar and a cancel button.
2. Spawn this second program whenever the user "drops" something. This program will create the target file immediately and start filling it with data. It will maintain appropriate locks on the file until it is done downloading, at which point the "downloader" will exit.

If you're going to keep the "downloader" threads in the originating program, you will need some kind of download manager so that the user can get appropriate feedback on their downloads.

Comment: Accidentally upvoted. This doesn't solve the problem! You need to know where the file was dropped, as I strongly believe that webbrowsers cannot know this too unless they're using temporary files and a filesystemwatcher. For example, someone dragged an image to a folder on the desktop. What will the command line parameters be?If I could know where the file was dropped, it wouldn't be a problem at all even in the same application. Putting this in a different process actually doesn't help anything.

Comment: Perhaps the approach taken by a web browser of prompting for the save location rather than allowing a drop is more appropriate?

Comment: As soon as you ask for a location using a dialog, the whole idea of drag-and-drop isn't appropriate anymore.